# Question about enrichment score (ES) and NES from GSEA

Tags: gene-expression, pathway, gsea, go-enrichment

I have two results from two separate GSEA runs (2 different inputs / samples with same gene sets), and i want to know which sample has the most enrichment about specific pathway (gene set).

I want to compare the ES from the two different runs, looking at the same gene set. Can I use ES (or NES) from two different GSEA analysis about same gene set?

or should I combine the input dataset into one, and run the analysis again?

Comment: Usually GSEA is not applied to samples but to comparisons. Could you further explain what is your input and the method used for GSEA? Perhaps it is one I haven't heard of (there are many enrichment methods not only the one from the broad institute)